# What's the purpose of the method bytecode limit?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java?lq=1): there is a 64kb bytecode limit on Java methods.

What benefit does this provide to the compiler? GCC will happily compile multi-megabyte C methods -- what's the reasoning behind this design decision? Is it just, as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689798/why-does-java-limit-the-size-of-a-method-to-65535-byte), to limit poor programming practices, since 64kb methods are massive? Or is there some specific benefit to the limit being 64kb rather than some other number?

Comment: Aside from anything else, it means that any location in the method can always be addressed using 2 bytes... that could be useful in terms of jump locations, try/catch areas etc.

Comment: I suspect it's the same reason that PC-DOS had a 640kb limit.

Comment: @JonSkeet - interestingly, there's a `goto_w` instruction that uses a 4-byte offset.

Comment: @kdgregory: Very interesting. There's a note about that within the JVM spec, in fact: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.goto_w

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Offsets in the method bytecode are 2 bytes long (called "u2" in the class file format specification). The maximum offset that can be expressed with u2 is 64kB.

The offsets appear in the actual instructions, such as the `if*` bytecodes, that are followed by two bytes containing the offset delta of the branch. Also, other class file attributes like the `StackMapTable`, `LocalVariableTable`, `Exceptions` and others contain offsets into the bytecode.

If offsets were u4, then methods could be longer, but *all* class files would also be larger.  It's a trade-off.

Comment: So the benefit is that it ensures alignment? What is u2?

Comment: u2 is a an unsigned 2 byte integer, I just updated the answer. The benefit is that it tasks less space in the class file.

Comment: *Which* offsets? There are a lot of uses of `u2` in the JVM Spec. What specific part are you referring to?